# My temp file for my school.

Tags: templates

I finally finished making thesis template for my school. the outfit is like it should be. It tried to make tex file as simple as possible and I made some my own command to make it even easier to understand. The idea is, that people would just copy class file and link that, so after that they don't need to pay attention to layout settings.

Before I give it forward, I want to ask you guys to check class file, if it is possible make even simpler or better. 
Here is link for file: https://www.overleaf.com/7042012gcqktjrzwsxp it is just a template text, no real thesis. You can give my some good tips, what can be done better(and how).

If you feel that this subject doesn't belong to here, let me know and I will delete this.

Comment: Your class file should get a license and authorshi statement if you want others to safely use it.

Answer (score 5):

Probably it's not a good fit for this site, but I'll make a cw answer here (others may add to it). If you want to ask about specific tex issues, better make  small example in new questions just asking about one point at a time.

I didn't look at your class but there are several odd things in the example document. (The file is not as bad as the length of this list makes it seem, but since you asked for comments.....)

---

```
\sloppy %Even spacing in text
```

You shouldn't encourage `\sloppy` certainly not as a document wide default. It allows  arbitrarily *uneven* spacing, in order to help with tricky linebreaking in special cases.

```
\makecover %Make cover page

\newpage
```

You should not need `\newpage` (if your class is defining `\makecover` to make a cover page it should have handles the page breaking internally.)

```
\section*{\MakeUppercase{Sisällysluettelo}}
```

There should be no formatting in the argument to headings within the document, if the design needs uppercased section headings that can be coded into the class definition of `\section*`

```
\underline{\textbf{HUOM!}}\\
```

This is presumably some kind of fake heading, it would be much better to use a latex sectioning command (perhaps a custom one defined in the class) for example this markup would allow the page to break immediately after the heading which a real heading command always prevents.

```
”sokeaksi”
```

looks odd to me, with two right quotation marks, but language customs vary a lot here, perhaps that's OK.

```
 F = 0,65\times (\mathrm{afk}_{c} sin \kappa_{r})
```

probably this is just filler text but anyway `sin` should presumably be `\sin`

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
```

It's normally better to use bibtex (or biber/biblatex) to manage the bibliography rather than manage it by hand.

```
\MakeUppercase{PROJEKTISUUNNITELMA}
```

again this seems to be a fake heading

```
\value{chapter}
```

That will expand to `\c@chapter` and be the left side of an assignment, don't you get a missing number error at that point?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering

\label{my-label}
```

The `\label` here will reference the current section, not the table as it is used with no `\caption`.

```
\subsection*{\textbf{3 TYÖNSUORITTAMINEN}}
```

as above there shouldn't be `\textbf` formatting in a heading, but also why use unnumbered sections and then number by hand?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what David said, I think the look of your tables could be improved, see this for example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, belowskip=4pt}

\begin{document}
%For creating a tables, you can use this page to help http://www.tablesgenerator.com/
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Kaksi lastuamisarvoyhdistelmää 25CrMo4-nuorrutusteräksen sorvaukseen}% \protect\viite{(}{Varis97}{34}{}.} % If you use "viite" inside of caption, you have use "\protect", so it will work. I've commented the citation (I think this is a citation) only to make the code compilable
\label{table:Lastuamis}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule   
Lastuamisnopeus, $v$ & Syöttö, $f$  & Lastuamissyvyys, $a$ & Pinnankarheus, $R_{a}$\\
  $[$m/min$]$ & $[$m/r$]$ & $[$mm$]$ & $[\mu$m$]$\\ 
\midrule  
  200 & 0,1 & 2 & 1,6\\ 
  180 & 0,3 & 2 & 2\\ 
  170 & 0,4 & 2 & 1,6\\ 
  160 & 0,5 & 2 & 1,6\\ 
  150 & 0,2 & 2 & 1,6\\ 
  140 & 0,15& 2 & 1,6\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%This table is cut manually to show how to cut two tables. If possible, use longtable package. It is easier. You can see example of longtable in appendix IV
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks good, but I did as my school outfit guide says..

Comment: @pinq- Tell them to change their outfit guide, ahahahah!